# Pass a model from a java server to a webpage using mustache or handlebars

Tags: javascript, java, html, handlebars.js, mustache

I am trying to pass a value from a server to a html page using mustache but I cannot figure out how to do that. I am at a loss here. I looked though some tutorials but I got even more lost with them.

So here is where I am trying to pass the user information from the server

```
@RequestMapping(value = HOME_URL_MAPPING)
public String inventory(final Model model) {

    //pass in user stuff gus

    String myRole = "HQ";
    //USER_ROLE = userRole
    model.addAttribute(USER_ROLE, myRole);
    return controllerHelper.createUrl(INVENTORY, WebGlobals.HOME);
}
```

And this is the html that I am trying to send the data to.

```
{{>partials/header}}
<script>
var haveClicked = false; 
var currentUserRole;

function checkUserRights()
{
  currentUserRole = "HQ";

  if(haveClicked == false)
  {

    switch (currentUserRole)
    {
        case "ADMIN":
            alert("Opening ADMIN Rights");

                 $('<a href="/inventory/view">Group1</a>').appendTo($('body'));
                 $('<a href="/inventory/approve">Group2</a>').appendTo($('body')); 

            haveClicked = true;
            break;
        case "HQ":
            alert("Opening HQ Rights");
            $('<a href="/inventory/view">Group1</a>').appendTo($('body'));
            haveClicked = true;
            break;
        default:
            alert("Opening A Rights");
            $('<a href="/inventory/approve">Group2</a>').appendTo($('body'));
            haveClicked = true;
    }


}
```

}

```
{{>partials/footer}}
```

I just don't know how to pass the information from the server to the html.
I tried stuff like this and some other options, but I think I am missing a important step

Here is one thing that I have tried that I think is on the right path;

```
<select class="user-roles ">
{{#userRoles}}
    <option value={{ userRole }}>{{ "HQ" }}</option>

{{/userRoles}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you already tried or not. If I can suggest you something : try to make all work just in html without using any server side return and then add your data returned by the server. You can take theses examples to start with : https://jsfiddle.net/ChristopheThiry/r6whn1ao/ or https://jsfiddle.net/ChristopheThiry/L34f7rm2/